# Adding serial number to each of the records in a text file using Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm looking for a solution here to my simple silly problem here.
Say, I have a huge 10GB text file with records delimited by '\n' and I provide the file as a input to the Hadoop framework.
The output should be a file such that it maintains the same order of the records as the input file but with a serial number in front of every record.

For e.g.,

If I have a input text file say,

```
this is line one
this is line two
this is line three
this is line four
-----------------
-----------------
```

output file should be,

```
1 this is line one
2 this is line two
3 this is line three
4 this is line four
------------------
-----------------
```

Edit: Say instead of a 10GB file I have a 10 TB file, so what could be done now?
Instead of handling the file using Hadoop way what could be the other best approach to do it rather faster?

Moreover, I also want to use multiple reducer not a single reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you would benefit anything from Hadoop for such a trivial operation, compared to just opening the file, reading line by line and storing each line in a new file (with a sequence/serial number prepended).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with pap, no need for Hadoop here. Check the command [nl](http://ss64.com/bash/nl.html), it adds the line number before each line of the file. Just store the output in a new file.

```
$ cat testFile
line1
line2
line3

$ nl testFile
   1   line1
   2   line2
   3   line3
```

Comment: Say instead of a 10GB file I have a 10 TB file, so what could be done now? If handling the file using Hadoop is not the proper way what could be the other best approach to do it rather faster?

Comment: What you have to take into account is that distributed processing (like hadoop) is, well, distributed. So yo have to factor in the overhead of transmitting the raw data out to the processing nodes as well as receiving and merging all the results. For a net gain, the cost of processing must outweigh the cost of distribution and merging. In your example, a larger file would actually make the case for distribution even less compelling, for such a trivial processing step (add id to each line). One tip would be two harddrives, one for reading from and one for writing.

Comment: The problem I see is how you plan to maintain the numbering on Hadoop. If you are able to split the files into subfiles, each of them with their numbering from 1..n, then I will use Hadoop. If you require to have a global numbering of the lines, then it is tricky to implement in Hadoop. You may require additional preprocessing that may be actually more costly.